# How can Load unstructured Excel to SQL table

Tags: ssis

deleted becuase of reasons thank  you all
please please please

Comment: Please do not post images.  What have you tried?  What DB technology are you using?

Comment: Hi @bihon this link (if you could have just searched) explains how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017 Besides, I do not see anything UN-structured.